# Text percentage

Tags: android, eclipse, text, percentage

I put this code but the problem with the percentage gives me a warning, where shall I put them?

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3">
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="14">
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your full layout XML and error report.

Comment: What percentage? width or height?

Comment: Hamis Shatu, when I posted, it gave me (Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.) and (It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.)

Comment: Artoo Detoo, yes, with the text below, which is not there :)

Comment: its saying...your code should be 4 space left to the question border....Now, paste your code in question and then select your whole code...and press CTRL+K...your code will be formated.

Answer (score 0):

try as below...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="20" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="#FF00FF" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="14"
        android:background="#FFFF00" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="#00FFFF" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: **fill_parent** is deprecated since API Level 8... should use **match_parent**, instead.

Comment: Can you type me a program? please? :)
I go sick of these fixes, I just want a title in top and just 1.text (I'll add more), at the and their size is % Im using Android 1.6
Im doing this for the past 4 days, Im a newbie!